# Mysql subquery optimization - count

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, query-optimization, subquery

i have these subqueries in a main query used to fetch some events:

```
SELECT [...],
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WEventUser WHERE WEventUser.eID=e.eID AND favorited=1) as numfavorited,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WEventUser WHERE WEventUser.eID=e.eID AND subscribed=1) as numsubscribed,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WEventUser WHERE eID=e.eID AND WEventUser.uID=2 AND favorited=1) as favorited,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WEventUser WHERE eID=e.eID AND WEventUser.uID=2 AND subscribed=1) as subscribed,
[...] WHERE...etc.
```

structure of WEventUser is quite simple

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `WEventUser` (
  `eID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `uID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `favorited` int(1) unsigned default '0',
  `subscribed` int(1) unsigned default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`eID`,`uID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

These subqueries are really expensive. Can you help me finding an alternative (like a single join)?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I'm selecting from a main WEvents table that is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wevents` (
`eID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `ecID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `eName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `eDescription` longtext,
 `eIsActive` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `eIsValidated` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 `eDateAdded` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `eDateModified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`eID`,`ecID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: what is e.eID in the query. please share the second table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a subqueries, it is enough to count values in the COUNT function, e.g. -

```
SELECT [...],
COUNT(IF(wu.favorited = 1, 1, NULL)) as numfavorited,
COUNT(IF(wu.subscribed = 1, 1, NULL)) as numsubscribed,
COUNT(IF(wu.uID=2 AND wu.favorited=1, 1, NULL)) as favorited,
COUNT(IF(wu.uID=2 AND wu.favorited = 1, 1, NULL)) as subscribed,
[...]
FROM
  WEventUser wu
WHERE...etc.
```

You can easily use this one if you want to join `WEventUser` with another table.

Comment: I'm selecting data from an other table, but I'm using your solution in this way:
     `SELECT [...],
     COUNT(IF(wu.favorited = 1, 1, NULL)) as numfavorited,
     COUNT(IF(wu.subscribed = 1, 1, NULL)) as numsubscribed,
     COUNT(IF(wu.uID=2 AND wu.favorited=1, 1, NULL)) as favorited,
     COUNT(IF(wu.uID=2 AND wu.favorited = 1, 1, NULL)) as subscribed,
    [...]
    FROM
       WEvents we LEFT JOIN WEventUser wu ON wu.eID=e.eID`
and it works!! Thanks!